# Powershell Switch Not Working

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

I have a powershell switch that is not working. Basically, no matter the choice you make, it proceeds to the submenus (ScanMenu and Export Menu), and THEN executes the other functions. I have tried moving the statements around, but it is not working. Does anyone have any insight to see what I am doing wrong?

```
 #Module Import Section

import-module ActiveDirectory

#Global Variables
$Title = "Audit Tool"

#Variables for Menus

$MainMenuMessage = "`nWhat would you like to do?"
$MainMenuOptions = [System.Management.Automation.host.ChoiceDescription[]] @("&Scan Network", "&Check AD Health", "&Quit")
$ScanMessage = "`nWhat would you like to scan for?"
$ExportMessage = "`nWould you like to export these results to .CSV?"
$ScanOptions = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] @("&Servers", "&Workstations", "&Quit")
$ExportOptions = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] @("&Yes","&No")
[int]$DefaultMainMenuChoice= 0
[int]$DefaultScanChoice = 0
[int]$DefaultExportChoice = 0
$MainMenu = $host.UI.PromptForChoice($Title, $MainMenuMessage, $MainMenuOptions,$DefaultMainMenuChoice) 
$ScanMenu = $host.UI.PromptForChoice($Title , $ScanMessage, $ScanOptions,$DefaultScanChoice)
$ExportMenu = $host.UI.PromptForChoice($Title, $ExportMessage, $ExportOptions,$DefaultExportChoice)

#Menus Function

switch($MainMenu){

  0 { switch($ScanMenu){
        0 { switch($ExportMenu){
                    0 { Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like "Windows Server*"} -Property * | Export-CSV WindowsServer.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8}
                    1 { Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like "Windows Server*"} -Property * | Format-Table Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemServicePack,OperatingSystemVersion -wrap -Auto}
        1 { switch($ExportMenu){
                    0 { Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -NotLike "Windows Server*"} -Property * | Export-CSV Workstations.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8}
                    1 { Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -NotLike "Windows Server*"} -Property * | Format-Table Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemServicePack,OperatingSystemVersion -wrap -Auto}
            }
          } 


        }
      }
   }
 }

 1 { invoke-expression -Command .\ADScan.ps1}
 2 { invoke-expression -Command Exit}  

}
```

Comment: try `switch([int]$MainMenu)` (using int on all your switches)

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your intention, and you were pretty close if I am right. It appears that you want to prompt the user for input whenever `$MainMenu`, `$ScanMenu`, or `$ExportMenu` are invoked within the `Switch`. Instead they are all being invoked immediately, and it appears to be callously ignoring your choices. That's because that is exactly what is happening.

When you define:

```
$MainMenu = $host.UI.PromptForChoice($Title, $MainMenuMessage, $MainMenuOptions,$DefaultMainMenuChoice)
```

It is prompting you to make that choice right then and there, and saving the result in `$MainMenu`. I think what you want to do is wait until it gets to the `Switch`, and prompt at that point, and act accordingly to the response. What you can do is define that as a scriptblock, and then invoke it later to prompt the user when you're ready. It would look like this:

```
$MainMenu = {$host.UI.PromptForChoice($Title, $MainMenuMessage, $MainMenuOptions,$DefaultMainMenuChoice) }
```

Then later you can invoke that scriptblock to prompt the user for what they want to do, and process your cases accordingly:

```
Switch($MainMenu.Invoke()){
    '0' {Switch($ScanMenu.Invoke()){...}}
    '1' {& .\ADScan.ps1}
    '2' {Break}
}
```